# How to delay 3rd party stats javascripts

Tags: javascript, load

i want to delay 3rd party stats java scripts..like revolver maps,feedjit,whos.amung.us
(stats scripts )
how to ?
if i use "defer".it defers for lifetime.how do i delay them
thankx in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [delay the loading of 3rd party javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323888/delay-the-loading-of-3rd-party-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeOut(function,1000);` to delay the execution of a function by 1000ms (1s)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're talking about libraries that are loaded by just including a `script` element? I guess something like this should work:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var headElement = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
  var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
  scriptElement.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptElement.src = 'http://my.library.url/my.library.js';
  headElement.appendChild(scriptElement);
}, 3000);
```

This should schedule your library to be injected 3 seconds later.

If you need to also run some code when it's loaded, include this somewhere in the middle:

```
  scriptElement.onload = function() {
    myLibraryInitFunction(myLibraryInitParameters);
  }
```